# Printing images to 200dpi printer

Tags: dpi, pixelation

I am trying to print these images to a 200dpi Datamax label printer:

[image]

When they print, they are really pixellated. How can I resolve this?
The image size is 2.5cmx2.5cm and I am printing the image at this size.

I don't really know much about images/printing, so I am hoping this is something simple.

The image I have inserted is:
1000 x 1000 pixels
Print sie 25x25 mm
1016 x 1016 ppi
Indexed Colour (2 colour)

Here is a photograph of a label from the old printer, using the old software.
The top image is from the old system (same printer).
The bottom one is from my system. They are both approx 2.5cm.
Mine is visibly more pixelated and i don't understand why.

[image]

Mick

Comment: what is the image resolution you are using to print? Because if it's less than 200dpi you're still going to see it pixelated, since the printer has a higher resolution than the image you're trying to print.

Comment: The image above is the file I am trying to print.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to be the bearer of bad news, but if it looks like this...

[image]

...then that's as good as it's going to get. 200dpi is pretty low resolution for a printer and curves like this will always show of the pixelation that results to great effect.

I've reduced the res to 200dpi for this illustration. If you do the same when you're preparing files for that printer then you will know what quality you are going to get in advance.

Comment: Can you explain how you did that? That is what they look like printed. This is confusing because the old software (I am writing new) prints the image to the printer without this pixelation, it almost looks like vector.

Comment: I just went to Image > Image size... in Photoshop and set the size to 2.5cm square and the resolution to 200dpi. I've actually doubled up the res on the uploaded version to make it easier to see, but that's by the by. Was the old software running prints through the same, 200dpi device? If so, it's possible that the software was adding some sort of anti aliasing, assuming that the printer is capable of printing tints of black (grey tone work) as well as solids?

Comment: Same printer, no anti aliasing.

Comment: I notice that you've added a bit more info now. Have you tried saving the image at 200dpi at the exact size that it will print? Like I've described above. The nasty artefacts that you are seeing may be the result of the software interpolating your high res image down to the printer's native 200dpi.

Comment: Yes, I am using GIMP and have set the image size to 25mm by 25mm which is the space I print at. I have also changed the resolution to 199x199 pixels/in.

Comment: the bottom half of the OP photo, the "artifacts" seem to radiate from the center (or are perpendicular to line describing the circle), so there may be something else going on here. Some of it is assuredly paper bleed and print head inaccuracy. The circle is also physically smaller, so scaling is occurring somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

It was the printer driver. I am now opening a socket and writing DPL to the printer and the image is perfect.

Mick